# Pointer on 2D array segfaults

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following minimal example where my main function calls two different functions `function1()` and `function2()`. They both want to work on a table, which needs to be generated in the first run of `function1()`. In my actual program the table is much bigger, that is why I don't want it hard-coded in the program memory as a global variable but calculated in the first round of the code. I declared the table static, such that it keeps the assigned values when the functions are leaved. I am not sure if the `tblPtr` needs to be `static` too. Why do I get a SEGFAULT here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void genTbl(unsigned int encodeTbl[][2])
{
    int nn,mm;
    for (nn=0; nn < 3;nn++){
        for (mm=0; mm < 2; mm++){
            encodeTbl[nn][mm] = nn+mm; //some example
        }
    }
}
unsigned int **tblPtr;          //pointer to table
static unsigned int function1()
{
    static int t1=0;
    static unsigned int tbl[3][2];
    if(t1==0){ //only gen table in first round
        t1++;
        genTbl(tbl);
        tblPtr = &tbl; //assign pointer 
        t1++;
    }
    return (tbl[2][2]);
}
static unsigned int function2()
{
   //also wants to work with tbl
   return (tblPtr[2][2]);   //SEGFAULT
}

int main()
{
    int cnt=0;
    while(cnt<5){
        int f1 = function1();
        printf("function1 return: %d\n", f1);
        int f2 = function2();
        printf("function1 return: %d\n", f2);
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `tblPtr = &tbl;` not a very good conversion - I must say.

Comment: Hard mix of static and dynamic arrays, specially void genTbl(unsigned int encodeTbl[][2])

Comment: try tblPtr= tbl

Comment: @grapes, why dynamic, it is basically defined at compile time how big the table is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `function1()`, you already invoked [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You have defined the array like `static unsigned int tbl[3][2];`, so the valid access would be `tbl[i][j];`, where `0<i<3` and `0<j<2`. Thus, in the code

```
return (tbl[2][2]);
```

is using memory out of bounds, it's [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). You have the same problem also in `function2()` also.

That said, the statement

```
 tblPtr = &tbl;
```

is invalid, and it is a constraint violation. Any conorming  compiler with proper warnings enabled will warn you about the statement. YOu need to change the type of `tblPtr` to be a pointer to an array of 2 `int`s, something like

```
 unsigned int (*tblPtr)[2];
```

and then, the assignment would stand valid.

Comment: @jonnyx You have got the same problem in function2 also.

Answer (score 0):

Declare tblPtr as a user defined type with

```
typedef unsigned int myType[3][2];
myType **tblPtr;          //pointer to table
```

With this method you declare it explicitly as a pointer to a bidimensional array of unsigned ints.
And then put `static unsigned int tbl[3][2]` outside of function 1

Comment: well when i put it outside of my function, it will be in program memory and not lying in stack... I have to few space available for that.